# Android apk not workin

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

While running application from android studio application works fine but after build release apk it is not working but debug apk works fine.

i want to run release apk in the device.

Comment: let me clear your release apk not working and debug does right?

Comment: yes you are right.

Comment: Are there any error logs or infos when you run release apk?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in menifeast i think it will work.

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...>
       
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: let me try this solution..

Answer (score 0):

Have you check the minSdkVersion in the build.gradle?

If the android version don't match the api level of the app then it can't be installed.

Here are the reference for the api level: https://apilevels.com/